# Why is my destructor not being called?

Tags: c++, oop, destructor

My destructor is not being called when the program exits.  The object is a singleton, perhaps I am missing something?

Here is the header and cpp file:

```
#ifndef MYSQLCONNECTOR_H
#define MYSQLCONNECTOR_H

/* Standard C++ headers */
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

/* MySQL Connector/C++ specific headers */
#include <driver.h>
#include <connection.h>
#include <statement.h>
#include <prepared_statement.h>
#include <resultset.h>
#include <metadata.h>
#include <resultset_metadata.h>
#include <exception.h>
#include <warning.h>

class MysqlConnector {
private:
    static bool instanceFlag;
    static MysqlConnector* mysqlConnector;

    MysqlConnector() {

    };
public:
    static sql::Driver *driver;
    static sql::Connection *conn;
    static MysqlConnector* getInstance();

    virtual ~MysqlConnector() {
        instanceFlag = false;
        conn->close();
        delete conn;
        std::cout << "called" << std::endl;
    };
private:

};

#endif  /* MYSQLCONNECTOR_H */
```

And the cpp file

```
#include "MysqlConnector.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace sql;

bool MysqlConnector::instanceFlag = false;
MysqlConnector* MysqlConnector::mysqlConnector = NULL;

MysqlConnector* MysqlConnector::getInstance() {
    if (!instanceFlag) {
        mysqlConnector = new MysqlConnector();
        instanceFlag = true;

        try {
            driver = get_driver_instance();

            /* create a database connection using the Driver */
            conn = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");

            /* turn off the autocommit */
            conn -> setAutoCommit(0);

            /* select appropriate database schema */
            conn -> setSchema("exchange");

        } catch (SQLException &e) {
            cout << "ERROR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
            cout << " (" << __func__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
            cout << "ERROR: " << e.what();
            cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
            cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << ")" << endl;

            if (e.getErrorCode() == 1047) {
                cout << "\nYour server does not seem to support Prepared Statements at all. ";
                cout << "Perhaps MYSQL < 4.1?" << endl;
            }
        } catch (std::runtime_error &e) {
            cout << "ERROR: runtime_error in " << __FILE__;
            cout << " (" << __func__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
            cout << "ERROR: " << e.what() << endl;
        }

        return mysqlConnector;
    } else {
        return mysqlConnector;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably look into what people have to say about singletons.

Comment: What are they saying about them, I'll take a look, reference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your destructor is not getting called because nobody is calling `delete` for an object created with `new`:

```
mysqlConnector = new MysqlConnector(); // Where's the corresponding call to delete?
```

You may consider using a smart pointer instead (I would suggest `std::unique_ptr`, if you can afford C++11). That would automatically called `delete` on the encapsulated object when the smart pointer itself is destroyed.

Another possibility is to not use pointers at all, and have a static data member of type `MysqlConnector`. `getInstance()` could then return a reference (rather than a pointer) to that object.

Comment: if the program exits then these `new`d objects get destoryed right? or is it that only the memory they occupy is reclaimed by the OS?

Comment: @Koushik: No, they do not get destroyed unless there is a call to `delete`. This call to `delete` may not be explicit - as is the case when a RAII wrapper such as a smart pointer is used, but it has to be there. If it is not there, the memory is leaked (unless some fancy pattern is used, but the OP's question does not suggest that). Then, at process termination the memory allocated by the process is claimed back by the OS.

Comment: so during programs termination the objects ,if not explicitly deleted, is left in a invalid state while its memory is reclaimed either ways rite?

Comment: I've tried to use the auto_ptr, however I think I am doing it wrong.  Is there an example of a singleton somewhere I can go by?

Comment: @Koushik: The object is not left in an invalid state, it could be left in a valid state and just not be destroyed. But yes, the memory is reclaimed by the OS aftere the process is terminated.

Comment: @MichaelICE: `auto_ptr` is deprecated in C++11, you should not use it. I'm sure there's plenty of examples how to create a singleton on SO, but beware - singleton is a rather dangerous design pattern. Many people would just tell you to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I'll look into alternatives. Any suggestions for a MysqlConnector class?

Comment: @MichaelICE: Uhm, what kind of suggestion? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
static MysqlConnector* mysqlConnector;
```

Is the pointer to the class. When you get the instance it just returns this pointer. You need to call `delete` on this static pointer for the destructor to be called.

If you do go ahead and call delete on this pointer, make sure you only do so when the program terminates though - since the next call to `getInstance()` will create a new object.

*EDIT - just spotted the instanceFlag so it won't create a new instance but would return a NULL pointer*

This is problematic since you might expect the Singleton to be the same object, but of course creating a new instance of it will mean that your data will not be persistent (even though you are accessing a singleton).

The OS will reclaim the memory regardless, so you might be better to expose the connection closing code and calling that by yourself?